# When was Electromagnetically Induced Transparency first introduced?

Tags: quantum-information, specific-reference, history, quantum-optics

The oldest paper I know regarding this topic was published in 1997 by Stephen E. Harris. But I am not sure if he is the first to introduce this idea. Could you tell me when and by who did introduce the EIT concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i could find with quick search EIT was first proposed by Jakob Khanin and graduate student Olga Kocharovskaya at Gorky State University, Russia, in 1986.

Comment: Thank. Surprisingly, I am working on EIT and have no idea who invented it.

Answer (score 1):

Try S. L. McCall and E. L.Hahn -- Phys. Rev. vol. 183, p.457 (1969).

Comment: This question is not a resource request (even though your answer would fail to answer that category as well), so could you please provide the relevant details from that paper?

Comment: I think he's saying he thinks the oldest known paper is from 1969 by McCall and Hahn "Self-Induced Transparency"... I don't have the time or the subscription to figure out if he's right...

Comment: @KyleKanos it didn't have the tag, but the question is pretty clearly worded as a resource request so I added the tag. Given that, I think this answer is valid, though it would certainly be better with more information.